# Client side decryption

Tags: android, encryption

My android application downloads some encrypted message from the server and stores it locally. The application needs to decrypt the message later on even during offline. The application will be publicly distributed so any users are able to decrypt the message.

Should I use a common password embedded in client side application or store the key together with the encrypted message in the server? What's is my best bet for this problem? I understand both are bad practice and would appreciate if there is a better solution.

#### ----- Edit -----

I am not able to disclose what I do but this should be sufficient to describe the scenario. However, the actual information is not as sensitive and private.

1. Any users can upload their, says bank account balance and lock it with their online banking password. The encrypted password will be store in the database online.
2. App will download the encrypted passwords when the Internet is available.
3. Any users can access other users' bank account balances even when **offline**. The decryption of password and unlocking happens in the background.

The purpose of encryption is to mask the passwords from all users so that no user can access some user's online banking with the decrypted password.

Comment: You seem to have limited knowledge of crypto-related topics.  If any client can decrypt the message, who are you trying to hide the information from?  If the decryption key is stored client-side, anyone can decrypt the traffic between your client and server.

Comment: Who are you protecting the data from? Without more specific information you can't get a good answer. Add ore information to the question.

Comment: I added more description on my problem. Connection between client and server should be fine if encrypted with TLS. My problem is how can I decrypt any password at the client side and hide it from all users or any hackers because all the passwords will be stored at client side.

Answer (score 1):

Embedded secret key is not a good idea at all, that is the unforgiven  mistake that had been done by snapchat's developers. In your case, employing a TLS connection would solve the problem, then you can share the secret key through that secure connection without exposure for further procedures. i created another secure protocol based on Asymmetric key for sharing secret key over public network without using TLS protocol for android. here you can study the code :

https://github.com/Spentas/securechat/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/spentas/javad/securechat

TLS implementation is also included in the source code under websocket package if u want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of TLS connection. However, I need to store these encrypted information at the client side and after download from the server everything should work offline.